# fetch() with 'credentials: true' fails in Tampermonkey userscript in Chrome

Tags: cors, fetch, tampermonkey, userscripts

**The `Cookie`-header is missing when sending a `credentials: true`-`fetch`-request in a Tampermonkey userscript in Chrome even though CORS is configured correctly. What is the problem?**

Additional information:

The same code works as expected in a Tampermonkey userscript in Firefox.

I have an API endpoint on a cross-origin server which is properly configured to accept a specific `fetch`-request with `credentials: true`.

This is my current code:

```js
fetch('https://example.com/api/my/endpoint', {
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

The `OPTIONS`-preflight-request to `example.com` is being made successfully and returns with the following headers:

```
access-control-allow-origin: https://requestingsite.com
allow: GET, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-methods: GET, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cookie, Authorization, Pragma
access-control-allow-credentials: true
```

After that, the `GET`-request to `example.com` is made. It works as expected in Firefox - it sends the necessary `Cookie`-header in the request.

It doesn't work in Chrome, though. The request in Chrome contains the necessary `Origin`-header and matches what is inside the header `access-control-allow-origin` returned by the server.